# Where should I start to implement a online video editor? -- Edit the video on the server

Tags: json, video, streaming

Our team want to make an online video editor web application.

We need below features for this application:

1. A media library which includes the videos on the target dir.
2. A view(play) window to play/pause the specific video on the media library.
3. Drag the video from the media library and drop it into a timeline.
4. Cut the video on the timeline.
5. Bond all the video fragments in the time line, preview it on the web, and save it in the server.

Some ideas as follow:

1. In this application we do not need to upload the video to client's side, all the edit work need to be done in the server side.
2. We want to use http request and JSON response as a communication protocol.
3. I can get the online video information like resource list, video duration, video format and whole stream from the JSON response.

Now the question is:

1. How to use the JSON response in the web side?
2. Is there any open source project which has implemented this application?
3. If no implemented open source project now, which technologies should I use in the web side? AngulaJS, PopcornJS?

I am totally new as a web application developer. So I do not know where I should start for this application. I only have 16 days for this application task.

Comment: What **is** your server side?

Comment: Thank you @PM77-1 . I am not sure about the server side now. But the basic idea is that we can ignore that side, we only send the http request to server and the server, which owns the the video, will edit the video. The web only send request and display the editor window as a GUI. And I am going to clarify with my colleague about the server side. It may takes some time, because he is in vacation.

Comment: @PM77-1 The server side use ffmpeg. And i want to do something like here:http://ninjastreet.kawasaki.com/VideoBuilder/BuildVideo.aspx

Comment: Is there anyone can guide on this